# Decomposing objects into their structural components in pcl

Tags: ros, pcl, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Do you know any pcl example or source code that does decompose objects into their components by using any kind of a method?

I know that there are SAC based segmentation methods that does primitive shape fitting but I don't think they are able to extract mug handles or other similar sub-components. Well you can get the handle after extracting the cylinder-like mug component, but I need sth that is able cluster other smaller parts also.

I need this just for visualization purposes, it is not required to run online/real time, it is adequate to be able to work on stationary scenes/inputs.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9196/decomposing-objects-into-their-structural-components-in-pcl/) by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not an expert in 3D segmentation, so if somebody is then please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that the problem of segmenting an object point cloud into different parts is still an open research question. I don't think there is anything built in to PCL which can perform this.

Some people are working on this problem (using [radial reflection](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1618045) or [bounding volume hierarchies](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4392592&tag=1) for example), but I don't see any released code.

---

Originally posted by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) with karma: 226 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1